# Jquery UI Dialog ... CSS in IE doesn't work like FF etc

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

If I write html to a Jquery UI dialog box it is naturally centred. I add a DIV and use some CSS ...

```
#printReport {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 880px; 
}
```

... and then

```
$("#printReport").empty().append(results);
```

to put text on the page - and it does what I want in FF/Chrome etc (left justified) ... but in IE (V7 and V8) the text is still centred.

Am I missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment, it was a problem in the CSS and nothing to do with dialog .. sorry

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming some of the parent div's are set to be centered,
eiter by using the deprecated  tag or by doing something like:

```
margin: 0 auto
```

in order to make it work you should do something like this:

```
body {
text-align: center
}

#printReport {
width: 880px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left
}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: yes there is a text-align: center further up but I would have thought my printReport div with its over-riding lext-align:left would sort it.

Comment: I meant to add ... I put the margin 0 in but it makes no difference. I sure it's something glaringly obvious that I am missing.

Comment: is there a way you can pastebin the complete html structure of that page and the css?

Comment: It seems it was nothing to do with jquery dialog. It was IE refusing to parse the entire CSS file. The reason was a mis-placed quotation mark (a typo) in the file ... all other browsers were happy to ignore the typo but IE simply binned it all.

Comment: hehe... that sucks. you should try find some good editor that does syntax highlighting for css and js. eclipse pdt is a good free one for example. that way you'll catch those things much easier.

Comment: as a side comment, i can recommend you to get modernizr and the css reset from html5boilerplate. this will make your life a whole lot easier for cross browser supporting development :)